# mod_wsgi for correct version of python3

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, mod-wsgi

I am setting up a Django server on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and I am having trouble installing mod-wsgi with the correct version of python. I have built my site locally with python 3.3, and Ubuntu 12.04 comes bundled with python 3.2. I suppose I could, but would rather not just use 3.2 instead of 3.3, so I installed python 3.3 alongside 3.2. I have everything installed for python 3.3 except for mod-wsgi.

On my local machine that is running python3.3 installing [libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3) with `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` installs it for python3.3. However on the Ubuntu server, running that same code installs it for python3.2 such that the web server runs 3.2 and can't find django.

Is there a way to disable python3.2, or point the script to install it for python 3.3?

EDIT: after looking into it more, python3.2 was not bundled with ubuntu, instead it was installed with libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3

Comment: Could you share how you solved this, if at all? Thank you!

Comment: @Visionscaper I ended up just changing the project to use a lower version of Python. The vast majority of the code is the same for both Python versions so it was mostly a matter of re-installing dependencies for the proper Python version

Comment: I found the solution, so I wrote my answer below!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found out how to build mod_wsgi, to be used with Python 3.3.5, on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

The trick is to be able to install the python3.3-dev package, which isn't supported on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS ("precise"). There is a 3rd party repository maintained by Felix Krull that makes old and new Python builds available (Kudos to Felix!):

https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/deadsnakes

To install Felix's repository:

> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
> sudo apt-get update
> ```

Before starting to build mod_wsgi we need the apache2-dev package ...

> ```
> sudo apt-get install apache2-dev
> ```

... and get the python3.3-dev package (this actually installs python3.3 as well!)

> sudo apt-get install python3.3-dev

Download the mod_wsgi code and build it by providing the path to the freshly installed Python libs and headers (/usr/bin/python3.3). The download link with the latest mod_wsgi release can be found at:

[https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/releases](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DownloadTheSoftware)

> ```
> cd /usr/local/src
> sudo wget https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/modwsgi/mod_wsgi-3.4.tar.gz
> sudo tar -zxvf mod_wsgi-3.4.tar.gz 
> cd mod_wsgi-3.4/
> sudo ./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python3.3
> sudo make
> sudo make install
> ```

mod_wsgi.so is placed in /usr/lib/apache2/modules/

**Optional step:**
Since they were missing, I manually (re)created the wsgi.conf and wsgi.load files in /etc/apache2/mods-available (although I didn't have to set any specific option).

wsgi.conf:

> ```
> <IfModule mod_wsgi.c>
>
>     # See http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives
>
>     #WSGISocketPrefix: Configure directory to use for daemon sockets.
>
>     #WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/apache2/wsgi
>
>     #WSGIPythonOptimize: Enables basic Python optimisation features.
>
>     #WSGIPythonOptimize 0
>
>     #WSGIPythonPath: Additional directories to search for Python modules,
>     #                overriding the PYTHONPATH environment variable.
>
>     #WSGIPythonPath directory|directory-1:directory-2:...
>
>
>     #WSGIPythonEggs: Directory to use for Python eggs cache.
>
>     #WSGIPythonEggs directory
>
>     #WSGIRestrictEmbedded: Enable restrictions on use of embedded mode. 
>
>     #WSGIRestrictEmbedded On|Off
>
>     #WSGIRestrictStdin: Enable restrictions on use of STDIN.
>     #WSGIRestrictStdout: Enable restrictions on use of STDOUT.
>     #WSGIRestrictSignal: Enable restrictions on use of signal().
>
>     #WSGIRestrictStdin On
>     #WSGIRestrictStdout On
>     #WSGIRestrictSignal On
>
>     #WSGIAcceptMutex: Specify type of accept mutex used by daemon processes.
>
>     #WSGIAcceptMutex default
>
>     #WSGIImportScript: Specify a script file to be loaded on process start. 
>
>     #WSGIImportScript process-group=name application-group=name
>
>     #WSGILazyInitialization: Enable/disable lazy initialisation of Python. 
>
>     #WSGILazyInitialization On|Off
>
> </IfModule>
> ```

wsgi.load:

> LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so

Finally, mod_wsgi can be enabled by creating symbolic links like this:

> ```
> cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
> sudo ln -s ../mods-available/wsgi.conf wsgi.conf
> sudo ln -s ../mods-available/wsgi.load wsgi.load
> ```

Let me know if this also worked out for you!

Comment: If you're installing on CentOS, you may need to update your Makefile. See https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/issues/detail?id=299

Comment: @ Visionscaper - this was a life saver - thanks  a lot for a great post!

Comment: @nicorellius you are welcome! This was a pain to figure out so I'm happy I could save you from this agony. :)

Comment: Latest versions of mod_wsgi are now here: https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/releases I managed to build against Python3.5 using this method.  Thanks

Comment: Thank you for describing how to create wsgi.load and wsgi.conf! I got stuck on that part going through the quick install guide. https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html

Comment: Thanks to @GMeister and @Visionscaper for this insight.  This helped with an error I had trying to install `mod-wsgi` using pip3 on a python 3.8 installation.  All I had to do was to add `apt-get -y install python3.8-dev` and then `pip3 install mod-wsgi`.  I didn't need to add the PPA, however.

Answer (score 1):

I did it in Centos 6.7, just create the file **wsgi.conf** in : */etc/httpd/conf.d* , specify the file path **mod_wsgi.so**: *LoadModule wsgi_module /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so*
After downloading and unzipping the file mod_wsgi_x.x.tar, you need to do something extra after specifying the version of python:

```
./configure  --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python3.4
LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/lib make
make install
```

This will embed the non standard directory location into the mod_wsgi.so, as explained **Graham Dumpleton** in the following link :
[GoogleGroups answers](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/modwsgi/F_eQkxKEcGM)